# How do I display a message after a file has been downloaded?

Tags: php, download

I have this PHP code and it works fine.

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="WTBak.zip"');
readfile($ArchiveFileName);
echo $ArchiveFileName;
unlink($ArchiveFileName);
```

My issue is, how do I give out a message after the last line (unlink) has been executed?

Thanks!

Comment: i don't think you can...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If this is not possible, is there some way of alerting the user that (at least) the download is ready. I know we cannot output any text before headers but I was wondering if there's a workaround.

Comment: @itsols: The user will be alerted when the 'Save file' dialog pops up.

Comment: You'll be corrupting the zipfile by echoing out the filename as you are. It'll be saved into the file along with the rest of the zip data you're sending. To do a proper file download you cannot sending anything EXCEPT http headers and the file's data.

Comment: @Marc, So far, with the tests done, I haven't noticed any corruption. Why do you think it should? And going by the PHP docs, I believe this is the method to adopt. Finally, IF corruption is a possibility, perhaps we can use MIME encoding. Just a thought...

Comment: @itsols: changing encodings has nothing to do with it. You're glueing a piece of dog poo to the bumper of a ferrari. It's still a ferrari, but no one's going to buy it from you until the poo's removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions:**

1. The client user should receive a message, this is kind of message sent to the client
2. The response is binary

**Abstract:**

1. sending binary information to the client along with text response would be possible if it is mhtml format, used in mails and each browser has (some do nto have) the support for multipart response. Let us not chose this way
2. sending binary information to respond one request (download file) and another response to another request (status of download) - this is a popular practice.

**Solution:**

1. **on server**: persist the status of download

   // pseudocode: log_download_event(seessionid, status='started')

   header('Content-Type: application/zip');

   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="WTBak.zip"');

   readfile($ArchiveFileName);

   echo $ArchiveFileName;

   unlink($ArchiveFileName);

   // pseudocode: log_download_event(seessionid, status='done')
2. **on server:** implement a php that will respond with a status of  download

   // pseudocode: $DownloadStatus=get_download_status(sessionid)

   echo '{staus:' + $DownloadStatus + '}'
3. **on client:** on some event trigger the download

   window.open("http://nowhere.com/download.php?resuorce=archive-file.zip");

   window.theTrackInterval = window.setInterval(trackDownload, 1000);

   var trackInterval = function(){

   $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {

   ```
   id(data.status=='ready'){

       cleanInterval(window.theTrackInterval);

       alert('download is done');

   }
   ```

   });

   }

This solution will start sending the ajax requests to the server every one second asking "is download done" and when it will receive confirmation "yest it is done" client will stop tracking and alert a message

**What is missed:**
the implementation of status persistence. i am not PHP guy - forgive me this gap

Comment: Thank you Pavel C. Your answer is beautifully laid out!

Comment: My only issue is how the line after unlink will ever be executed. Anyway let me check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look, if you give a message, it will be sent in the file and not shown to the user corrupting / changing the contents of the file. You cannot modify the headers as they've already been sent!

So, I feel, there is now way!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement from client. So I created a tool to show message after a file gets downloaded.

You can see at http://www.iamkumaran.com/xdownloader-a-flash-javascript-library/ and look for demo link.

Comment: Thank you Muthu Kumaran. I believe your Flash implementation is quite good. But I'm trying to do without Flash. Thanks anyway.