# laravel Response:download()->with() not working

Tags: laravel

return response()->download($resultPath."/".$csvfilename,$csvfilename, $headers)->with("success","success"); not working

how to pass parameter in return in laravel

Comment: There's 1000 different reasons why this wouldn't work and 1000 others of why it would work. You need to be more specific. Any error? Did you check if the file actually exists? Is the route even running?

Comment: develop.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::with()' in

Comment: You're sending a "download response" and trying to pass a success message to it. That doesn't make much sense, just remove the `->with("success","success")` bit

Comment: but i want to pass some message to view side

Comment: But you're not sending a view, you're sending a file. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835117/how-do-i-display-a-message-after-a-file-has-been-downloaded

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be able to do `return response()->with('success', 'success')->download(...)` but I'm not sure.

If you really need to check the success, try to set a header or to check the HTTP status code.